# How to convert subtitles version?

Tags: video, subtitles

When I for example download a `Game of Thrones S01E01 HDTV XviD-FEVER.avi` but I only have a `GoT_S01xE01_REWARD.sk.srt` subtitles, how do I convert them from `REWARD` to `FEVER` version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are downloading a movie or a TV series, there are different releases. The same movie can have different length, different frame rates or can be encoded using different methods. This leads to different versions of subtitles and when you have the bad one, they appear too early, too late or they are drifting out of sync during the movie, so even setting a delay wouldn't help you.

This is the reason why the most of the time you need the subtitles with the same version as your movie. For simpler conversion of subtitles in the `.srt` format I made a [srt-timer](https://github.com/Thyrst/srt-timer) script which can simply convert your subtitles to different verions for you.

At first, you will create a `reward2fever.sdiff` file with the conversion information that you'll get from `REWARD` and `FEVER` versions of subtitles of another language. Most of the time you will find English subtitles for all versions.

`srt_timer.py make_sdiff -o reward2fever.sdiff \
GoT_S01xE01_REWARD.en.srt GoT_S01xE01_FEVER.en.srt`

Then you'll just type this:

`$ srt_timer.py convert -s reward2fever.sdiff -o GoT_S01xE01_FEVER.sk.srt \
GoT_S01xE01_REWARD.sk.srt`

And you are done with the subtitles of your desired version.